# iptables using, goto + jump: what is the RETURN behaviour?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to work out what is the iptables behaviour when you have multiple custom chains and you sue a mix between -goto and -jump

Example:

```
INPUT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j CUSTOM-A

CUSTOM-A
few commands here...
iptables -A CUSTOM-A -i eth1 -p tcp -dport 80 -g CUSTOM-B
few optional commands here...
iptables -A CUSTOM-A -i eth1 -s 0/0 -g CUSTOM-B

CUSTOM-B
iptables -A CUSTOM-B few commands here... -j CUSTOM-C
iptables -A CUSTOM-B few commands here... -j CUSTOM-C
iptables -A CUSTOM-B few commands here... -j CUSTOM-C
iptables -A CUSTOM-B -i eth1 -s 0/0 -j RETURN

CUSTOM-C
iptables -A CUSTOM-C -s 0/0 -j LOG
iptables -A CUSTOM-C -s 0/0 -j DROP
```

With the above scenario packets matched on CUSTOM-A tcp/80 will go to CUSTOM-B and if they reach the bottom of the table they would RETURN. Is the RETURN actually returning the packet to INPUT since the packet got there via a goto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the RETURN actually returning the packet to INPUT since the packet got there via a goto?

This is what the man page says...

> -g, --goto chain
>   This specifies that the processing should continue in a user specified chain. Unlike the --jump option return will not continue processing in this chain but instead in the chain that called us via --jump.

So I would expect the return to be to the INPUT chain.

Comment: This was answered perfectly already. I'm going to comment an answer explaining this differently in case I ever google this again in 3 years. Ex 1: If INPUT jumps to CUSTOM-A which jumps to CUSTOM-B, then there are "3 stack frames". B returning will pop a stack frame, leading to CUSTOM-A. Ex 2: If INPUT jumps to CUSTOM-A which `goto`s to CUSTOM-B, then the CUSTOM-B stack frame replaces the CUSTOM-A "stack frame". There are "2 stack frames". B returning will pop a stack frame, leading to INPUT. Just as in the case of C code, `goto` pre-empts, `jump` function calls.

Comment: if only I knew what a 'stack frame' meant!

Comment: @Lethargos it's similar to calling a function and returning from a function in programming. The stack-frame stores where you were before the call (or the JUMP here). So when you -j into some chain, -j RETURN will continue the chain from where you jumped. -g will "forget" where you came from, so -j RETURN will not bring you back there. Similar to a goto in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Jump: a packet that matches with any jump rule, will go to the chain indicated by the jump. If the packet gets returned later on, it will be processed back by the chain that sent it on the jump, in the rule following said jump.

Goto: a packet that matches any goto rule, will go to the chain indicated by the goto. If the packet gets returned later on, it will not be processed back by the chain that sent it on the goto, but by the chain that sent it on the last jump, in the rule following said jump.